# slippery php SOAP syntax

Tags: php, soap

I am having trouble figuring out how to make soap requests.

First I load the wsdl document.

```
$sclient=new SoapClient('wsdl.asmx');
```

Then when i look in the return from __getFunctions() I have this string

```
simpleFunction( simpleFunction $parameters )
```

And in __getTypes() I have this string

```
struct simpleFunction{ string oid; string Username; string Password;}
```

I have been trying all kinds of combinations of arrays, SoapParams, and SoapVars, but I always get an error like this:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\path.php:21 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('handleSimpleUse...', Array) #1 C:\path(21): SoapClient->simpleFunction(Array)

Here is the code of my latest attempt

```
$sclient=new SoapClient('wsdl.asmx');

$params=array(
        new SoapVar('aaa',XSD_STRING,'oid'),
        new SoapVar('bbb',XSD_STRING,'Password'),
        new SoapVar('ccc',XSD_STRING,'Username')
    );

$result=$sclient->simpleFunction($params);
```

How am I supposed to correctly format this soap request?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with PHP SoapClient, but maybe this problem is because your SoapVar's have "Password" and "Username" with uppercase letters?

Comment: They were supposed to be capitalized in the first part of the question, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/ to generate classes to use from the wsdl file.